# Keep history in django to draw graphs

Tags: python, sql, django

I am looking for the best way to have an history of my models (interger & float fields) in Django.
I read [Keeping a history of data changes in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952913/keeping-a-history-of-data-changes-in-database) and it seems that triggers are the best option.

My idea is to stay database agnostic if possible.

How do you approach this issues in your django code ?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [Django Reversion](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/) app. It's probably the easiest way to implement what you want in your project, especially if you'd also like to restore earlier versions of your model(s). If not, it might be a bit overkill.

**Edit**: You should also examine [Django History](http://hg.piranha.org.ua/django-history/). Might be more along the lines of what you really need. However it hasn't been updated in a long time, you might have to just use it as inspiration for your custom solution.

Comment: I have been coding a simple django-history.
But still I would be interested to see what the best pratice to keep data in a database for graph purposes.

Comment: Well it's hard to say, depending what models do you have and what kind of graphs you want to generate from them etc. But one common/basic practice to optimize functionalities that deal with 'SELECT'-ing a lot of data is *denormalization* of some models.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to go with Triggers, [Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) do a similar job — it'll (probably) be less efficient than using a trigger, but you can attach a `post_save` signal to your models you want to track and do all the processing you need there.